# Is it mandatory to install WALinuxAgent?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I'm creating a custom vhd image to make it available in azure market place. Its an inbuild centos 7 machine and I want to load it as an image. Is it mandatory to have WALinuxAgent agent to be installed as part of the image? Here is the documentation which says to install it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/create-upload-centos#centos-70. I want to exclude that package from the image. Is that okay to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You do need it, otherwise the VM may not boot. This agent communicates with the Azure fabric to provide VM status amongst other things. You can find more information about it here: https://github.com/Azure/WALinuxAgent